# How to ignore special td node and its whole children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a DOM tree as follow :

```js
console.log($("table td:not(.customWrap)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
<table>
  <td class="noWrap">1</td>
  <td class="noWrap">2</td>
  <td class="customWrap">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td class="noWrap">3</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td class="noWrap">4</td>
</table>
```

I use a selector `$("table td:not(.customWrap)")` to get some node that include 1,2,4.

But with this selector, I filter the node `td.customWrap` successfully and not filter its children `<td class="noWrap">3<td>`.

Actually, I don't want to get the node that has `3`.

Comment: Please note that you are not closing your `<td>`

Comment: It is not clear from the screenshot, but make sure that all your <td> tags are children of <table> tag and close <td> tags as well, as mentioned in the previous comment :)

Comment: How about `table td:not(.customWrap):not(:only-child)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This : you have to just change  `$("table td:not(.customWrap * , .customWrap)")`

```js
$(function() {
  $("table td:not(.customWrap * , .customWrap)").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text())
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td class="noWrap">1
    <td>
      <td class="noWrap">2
        <td>
          <td class="customWrap">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td class="noWrap">3
                  <td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td class="noWrap">4</td>
</table>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Your suggestion save my time! Thanks. There is only one thing to consider that the `*` may be add memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just the first level you could give your parent table an identifier then use the greater-than sign (>) in your selector like:

```
"#parent_table > tbody > tr > td.noWrap"
```

```js
console.log( $("#parent_table > tbody > tr > td.noWrap").length + " Items" );
console.log( $("#parent_table > tbody > tr > td.noWrap").text() );
console.log( $("#parent_table > tbody > tr > td.noWrap") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="parent_table" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td class="noWrap">1</td>
    <td class="noWrap">2</td>
    <td class="customWrap">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="noWrap">3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="noWrap">4</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Would that work? since the table most likely is like `<table><tbody><tr><td class="noWrap">`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes, you're right... (Updated)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
var s = $("table td").filter(function() {
  return $(this).closest('.customWrap').length == 0
});
```

**Working demo**

```js
var s = $("table td").filter(function() {
  return $(this).closest('.customWrap').length == 0
});

console.log(s)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="noWrap">1</td>
    <td class="noWrap">2</td>
    <td class="customWrap">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="noWrap">3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="noWrap">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell it not to return nested table td

Note this code only works if you have 1 levels of nested tables

```js
console.log($("table tr td").not(".customWrap").not("table table tr td").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="a">
<tr>
<td class="noWrap">1<td>
<td class="noWrap">2<td>
<td class="customWrap">
  <table >
   <tr>
    <td class="noWrap">3<td>
   </tr>
  </table>
<td>
<td class="noWrap">4<td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: (Note That this will not work if there's more nested levels)

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Correct. I probably should have mentioned this in the answer. Thanks